# Chess960 human database?

Tags: chess960

Is there a database for the different starting positions of Chess960? I would like it to have only human played games, because it it was for engines, I'd have [lots of computer chess games.](http://computerchess.org.uk/ccrl/404FRC/opening_report_by_white_score.html#table_start)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of what you are looking for :
http://chess960jungle.blogspot.fr/2014/02/chess960-database-complete-games-2001.html